# bash script-fu, way to get text from middle of output (random spots)

Tags: command-line, awk

So basically, i'm trying to get the rating from an mp3 programattially, and using the command line tool id3v2, I can get the rating that my program puts it into:

```
$ id3v2 -R Drake\ -\ Over3.mp3
id3v1 tag info for Drake - Over3.mp3:
Title  : Over                            Artist: Drake
Album  : Thank Me Later                  Year: 2010, Genre: Unknown (255)
Comment: The highly anticipated debut    Track: 0
id3v2 tag info for Drake - Over3.mp3:
TPE2 (Band/orchestra/accompaniment): Drake
TIT2 (Title/songname/content description): Over
TPE1 (Lead performer(s)/Soloist(s)): Drake
TALB (Album/Movie/Show title): Thank Me Later
TYER (Year): 2010
TCON (Content type): Rap - Hip-Hop (255)
TPUB (Publisher): Cash money/Universal Motown
POPM (Popularimeter): Windows Media Player 9 Series, counter=0 rating=196COMM (Comments): (MusicMatch_Preference)[eng]: Very Good
COMM (Comments): ()[eng]: The highly anticipated debut from Drake is here! "Thank Me Later" is hotest album in the game.
APIC (Attached picture): ()[, 3]: image/jpg, 38227 bytes
COMM (Comments): (ID3v1 Comment)[XXX]: The highly anticipated debut
TRCK (Track number/Position in set): PUB
```

Which i can narrow down to

```
$ id3v2 -R Drake\ -\ Over3.mp3 | grep POPM
POPM (Popularimeter): Windows Media Player 9 Series, counter=0 rating=196COMM (Comments): (MusicMatch_Preference)[eng]: Very Good
```

## Problem:

I'm not sure how i can get 'rating=###` from this string.  My awk/sed-fu is weak :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep -o 'rating=[[:digit:]]\+'`

Works for me...

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using two calls of `grep` by using this one call of `sed`:

```
id3v2 -R Drake\ -\ Over3.mp3 | sed -n '/POPM/s/.*[[:blank:]]\(rating=\)\([[:digit:]]\+\)\([^[:blank:]]*\)[[:blank:]].*/\1\2\3/p'
```

You can choose what to output by removing backreferences. In your example, the backreferences output the following:

- `\1` - rating=
- `\2` - 196
- `\3` - COMM

Together: "rating=196COMM"

Comment: Why do you need two calls of grep?

Comment: @Andy: The OP's `grep POPM` plus your `grep -o ...`.

Comment: I think it can all be done in the one grep call.

Comment: @Andy: I'd like to see that.

Comment: *confused* Just use the grep call I gave?! You don't need to do the initial `grep POPM`. I don't think I'm going crazy here...

Comment: @Andy: Although the OP's data doesn't have other lines that contain text that would match the regex, by using a selector (two greps or in one sed), you can make sure that you're getting the data that you intend.

Comment: OK I'm with you. I kinda thought that for a single command's output like this the one grep would be fine, but certainly with yours you couldn't get a false positive. Cheers.

Comment: Yea, i kept the original grep POPM to make sure i'm getting the right data.  Never know when some band is gonna come out with a song named "rating=255" lol